# iOS - Create plist files on server

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I need to create some plist files that will be read on an iOS device... These plist files will contain language translations from items out of a database.  I know a plist file is just a specific XML format, but I don't know where I could get the schema.

Everything I've searched has pointed to creating the plist in an XCode environment.  We'll need to create the XML structure in a .NET environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the header for a plist, there's the DTD right there http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```